# Css trick for border between blocks but not between container and his blocks

Tags: css

I'm trying to find the ultimate CSS-trick to perform what seems to be a simple thing :

I want to see borders between the different blocks, but not see them between the container border and a block. In other words, I want no space between the container and the blocks, but space between the blocks.

Of course I could set some things like `border-left: 0px;` for the left blocks in the container for example, but I'd like something than can adapt to every circonstances, no matter how many blocks there are, how many lines they do in the container, etc, without having to apply a specific style to every block in the container.

In the example bellow, all borders are shown, even those I don't want to see (between container's borders and blocks themselves) :

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;   
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 1em;   
}

.block {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block" style="width: 50%;">Block1</div>
  <div class="block" style="width: 50%;">Block2</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="block" style="width: 75%;">Block1</div>
  <div class="block" style="width: 25%;">Block2</div>
  <div class="block" style="width: 30%;">Block3</div>
  <div class="block" style="width: 70%;">Block4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your question is not well phrased.  You can just eliminate the border on the container to answer your question as phrased

Comment: @DCR as you figured out i'm not english, so please be my guest and phrase it well ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the border off the actual element and putting it instead on its after pseudo element, with the pseudo element being 4px less wide and less high (4px being 2x the desired border width) gives the effect by overwriting the red borders adjacent.

This is a bit hacky as paddings, width of the red borders etc needs to be adjusted for in the settings.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;   
  rborder: 2px green solid;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.container::after {
  border: 2px green solid;
  content: '';
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
  height: calc(100% - 4px);
  display: inline-block
  z-index: 1;
}

.block {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block" style="width: 50%;">Block1</div>
  <div class="block" style="width: 50%;">Block2</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="block" style="width: 75%;">Block1</div>
  <div class="block" style="width: 25%;">Block2</div>
  <div class="block" style="width: 30%;">Block3</div>
  <div class="block" style="width: 70%;">Block4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not bad at all !! I'll try it asap, thank you very much

Comment: OK it works great but I'm no longer able to interact with the blocks ^^ They can't be clicked because they are under the ::after 
I have to be able to interact with them :/
Edit : found a trick with css `pointer-events`, have to check the compatibility

Comment: Forgot to say : it's a bingo ! Your method + `pointer-events` set on "none" seems to do the trick :) Thank you very much !

Comment: Thanks for the update - yes, I'd forgotten to think about whether you might want to interact with the stuff. Glad it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Use `flex` property instead of `width`. Want space between blocks, using `gap` property.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0 10px;
}

.block {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container flexbox">
      <div class="block" style="flex: 1;">Block1</div>
      <div class="block" style="flex: 1;">Block2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="flexbox">
        <div class="block" style="flex: 3;">Block1</div>
        <div class="block" style="flex: 1;">Block2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="flexbox">
        <div class="block" style="width: 30%;">Block3</div>
        <div class="block" style="width: 70%;">Block4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Huuum, it does not give the effect I want : we still see the blocks' borders between the container and the blocks ^^